# Can no longer access to internet with the new Tor browse bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, socks

I just updated my Tor browser bundle program to the new one, but the programs that were always supposed to use Tor can no longer connect to the Internet (I kept the same proxy preferences) ... However, Tor Browser works perfectly !

So what do I have to change on programs configurations to make things work as good as before?

With the old Tor version, I only used to change the SOCKS proxy to : 127.0.0.1 : 9050 on internet options and everything was working well.

Old version of Tor: 2.3 New Version: 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tor process in the Tor Browser Bundle is configured to listen for SOCKS connections on port 9150.

So you need to update the SOCKS configuration of the programs in question to use localhost:9150 as their socks proxy.